# I am having trouble linking Public API(unsplash) to JS and HTML pages

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have linked an API (Unsplash) to Javascript and Html page, however the search input box and button are not working to fetch the images fromt the API. Secondly the show more button should only appear when a search input has been made. (I'm new to JS and Linking API dynamically )

I have tried to add the async function, response and await response as well the url for the Unsplash.

I expected the search input and button to search for images from Unsplash API when search button is clicked. As well as the the show more button to show once the first search has been made

The images are not showing when the text is inputed in the search input and the search button is clicked. The show more button is showing on the page before the search is made.

Below is my code:

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Upcoming Events - Tallinn University HCI Hub</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Tallinn University HCI Hub</h1>
        <p>Connecting the World of Human-Computer Interaction</p>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="upcoming-events.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="featured-speakers.html">Featured Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="meetup-rooms.html">Meetup Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="networking-opportunities.html">Networking Opportunities</a></li>
            <li><a href="mentoring-program.html">Mentoring Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="hub-blog.html">Hub Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="speakers-container">
        <h2>Featured Speakers</h2>

        <form class="search" >
            <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for a presenter">
            <button id="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>

        <div class="speaker-results">
            
            <div class="speaker-result">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560523159-4a9692d222ef" alt="Speaker 1 Image">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/woman-holding-microphone-standing-on-stage-D0rMhzEwiEA" target="_blank">HCI Trends</a> 
            </div>

            <div class="speaker-result">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591115765373-5207764f72e7" alt="Speaker 2 Image">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/people-sitting-on-chair-in-front-of-table-wMRIcT86SWU" target="_blank">User Testing</a> 
            </div>

            <div class="speaker-result">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560439514-e960a3ef5019" alt="Speaker 3 Image">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/mens-black-blazer-DL-yyYDDNX4" target="_blank">Trust in Technology</a> 
            </div
            
        </div>

        <button id="show-more-button">Show more</button>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 Tallinn University HCI Hub</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
JS
const accessKey = "PwYO_lHIYAHEHFxcaI3HjKJrdgYwOUfrCPmN8x7EtDg"

const formEle = document.querySelector("form")
const inputEle = document.getElementById("search-input")
const speakerResults = document.querySelector(".speaker-results")
const showMore = document.getElementById("show-more-button")

let inputData = ""
let page = 1;

async function searchImages(){
    inputData = inputEle.value;
    const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${page}&query=${inputData}&client_id=${accessKey}`

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    const results = data.speakerResults

    if (page === 1){
        speakerResults.innerHTML = ""
    }

    results.map((result) =>{
        const imageWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        imageWrapper.classList.add("speaker-result");
        const image =document.createElement('img');
        img.src = result.urls.small
        img.alt = result.alt_description
        const imageLink = document.createElement('a');
        imageLink.href = result.links.html 
        imageLink.target = "_blank"
        imageLink.textContent = result.alt_deescription

        imageWrapper.appendChild(image);
        imageWrapper.appendChild(imageLink);
        speakerResults.appendChild(imageWrapper);
    });

    page++
    if(page > 1){
        showMore.style.display = "block"
    }
}

formEle.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    page = 1;
    searchImages()
})

showMore.addEventListener("click", () => {
    searchImages()
})
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser *developer* tools console? hint `const data` does NOT have a property called `speakerResults` - hint 2: you create `const image` ... then try to add properties to `img`

Comment: Thanks, the hints were helpful. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for disappearing "show more" after search submit is you are forget to close **speaker-results** div.

replaced the fetch by axios and done some fix on typo in function.

Below code is working. Please verify from your side. Added width and height as 100px just for proper visualisation. You can ignore it and add your own style.

```js
    
    

  const accessKey = "PwYO_lHIYAHEHFxcaI3HjKJrdgYwOUfrCPmN8x7EtDg"


const formEle = document.querySelector("form")
const inputEle = document.getElementById("search-input")
const speakerResults = document.querySelector(".speaker-results")
const showMore = document.getElementById("show-more-button")

let inputData = ""
let page = 1;

async function searchImages(){

    inputData = inputEle.value;
    const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${page}&query=${inputData}&client_id=${accessKey}`
  
    // const response = await fetch(url);
            const response = await axios.get(url);

    const data = response.data;

        const results = data.results;

    if (page === 1){
        speakerResults.innerHTML = ""
    }

    results.map((result) =>{
        const imageWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        imageWrapper.classList.add("speaker-result");
        const image =document.createElement('img');
        image.src = result.urls.small
        image.alt = result.alt_description
        image.style = "width:100px;height:100px"
        const imageLink = document.createElement('a');
        imageLink.href = result.links.html 
        imageLink.target = "_blank"
        imageLink.textContent = result.alt_deescription

        imageWrapper.appendChild(image);
        imageWrapper.appendChild(imageLink);
        speakerResults.appendChild(imageWrapper);
    });

    page++
    if(page > 1){
        showMore.style.display = "block"
    }
}

formEle.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    page = 1;
    searchImages()
})

showMore.addEventListener("click", () => {
    searchImages()
})
```

```html
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Upcoming Events - Tallinn University HCI Hub</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Tallinn University HCI Hub</h1>
        <p>Connecting the World of Human-Computer Interaction</p>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="upcoming-events.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="featured-speakers.html">Featured Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="meetup-rooms.html">Meetup Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="networking-opportunities.html">Networking Opportunities</a></li>
            <li><a href="mentoring-program.html">Mentoring Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="hub-blog.html">Hub Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="speakers-container">
        <h2>Featured Speakers</h2>

        <form class="search" >
            <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for a presenter">
            <button id="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>

        <div class="speaker-results">
            
            <div class="speaker-result">
                <img style="width:100px; height: 100px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560523159-4a9692d222ef" alt="Speaker 1 Image">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/woman-holding-microphone-standing-on-stage-D0rMhzEwiEA" target="_blank">HCI Trends</a> 
            </div>

            <div class="speaker-result">
                <img style="width:100px; height: 100px"  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591115765373-5207764f72e7" alt="Speaker 2 Image">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/people-sitting-on-chair-in-front-of-table-wMRIcT86SWU" target="_blank">User Testing</a> 
            </div>

            <div class="speaker-result">
                <img style="width:100px; height: 100px"  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560439514-e960a3ef5019" alt="Speaker 3 Image">
                <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/mens-black-blazer-DL-yyYDDNX4" target="_blank">Trust in Technology</a> 
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <button id="show-more-button">Show more</button>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 Tallinn University HCI Hub</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</html>
```